# Replace blank characters from a file line by line

Tags: csv, powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-ise

I would like to be able to find all blanks from a CSV file and if a blank character is found on a line then should appear on the screen and I should be asked if I want to keep the entire line which contains that white space or remove it.

Let's say the directory is `C:\Cr\Powershell\test`. In there there is one CSV file `abc.csv`.

Tried doing it like this but in PowerShell ISE the `$_.PSObject.Properties` isn't recognized.

```
$csv = Import-Csv C:\Cr\Powershell\test\*.csv | Foreach-Object {
   $_.PSObject.Properties | Foreach-Object {$_.Value = $_.Value.Trim()}  
}
```

I apologize for not includding more code and what I tried more so far but they were silly attempts since I just begun.

[This](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/930309e3-a273-4cb2-883c-ecbe0792dca1/remove-lineswhite-space-from-csv-file?forum=winserverpowershell) looks helpful but I don't know exactly how to adapt it for my problem.

Comment: What exactly is your question? How to prompt for user input? How to replace blank characters? Or how to process a file line by line? Those are three different questions, and you shouldn't mix them.

Comment: How to replace blank characters when going line by line and waiting for user input for each line. Sorry if I am mixing them up but even if I ask 3 different questions that wouldn't sove my problem. I would need all 3 in one

Comment: @CM2K do you want to delete the whole line or just replace the blank character

Comment: Given what you have right now that would basically mean writing the script for you.

Comment: @Paul delete the whole line if on that line there is a blank character. But this should be prompted on the screen if should I do this or not. Because some lines I have to keep

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers right now i'm trying like this for only trimming `(gc C:\CrPowershell\test\*.csv) | ? {$_.trim()-ne""}| set-content file.csv`. And I know that I am asking a lot, but I am bit over my head with this task

Comment: This is what i would like to have for my line by line prompt : `delete yes no`, but don't know how to use it: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730939.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok man here you go:

```
$yes = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&Yes", "Retain line."

$no = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&No", "Delete line."

$n = @()

$f = Get-Content .\test.csv  
foreach($item in $f) {

if($item -like "* *"){ 
    $res = $host.ui.PromptForChoice("Title", "want to keep this line? `n $item", [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]]($yes, $no), 0)

    switch ($res) 
    {
        0 {$n+=$item}
        1 {}
    }


} else {
    $n+=$item
}

}

$n | Set-Content .\test.csv
```

if you have questions please post in the comments and i will explain

Comment: oh, thank you! I will test it right away. I'm looking forward into learning more about PowerShell

Comment: it works. Thank you! the part i'm not exactly getting it how you are displaying the line with a space. `$n = @()` to n is being appended the item which falls into the if clause for yes. But how is a line being set up as being an item. I'm looking at `foreach($item in $f)` but I don't get it completely

Comment: @CM2K the line is being displayed in the dialog using the `$item` variable, the `$item` variable is indeed set up by the `foreach` statement ("item" is of course only an arbitrary name, could be anything you want). basically if you use get-content each line will be an array item, foreach cycles through the array and allways assigns the current item the variable name you use at the beginning of the statement, in this case `$item`

Comment: Great solution. No way I could have written this from my first day, I only have experience with sql but I understand it now, Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

`Get-Content` is probably a better approach than `Import-Csv`, because that'll allow you to check an entire line for spaces instead of having to check each individual field. For fully automated processing you'd just use a `Where-Object` filter to remove non-matching lines from the output:

```
Get-Content 'C:\CrPowershell\test\input.csv' |
  Where-Object { $_ -notlike '* *' } |
  Set-Content 'C:\CrPowershell\test\output.csv'
```

However, since you want to prompt for each individual line that contains spaces you need a `ForEach-Object` (or a similiar construct) and a nested conditional, like this:

```
Get-Content 'C:\CrPowershell\test\input.csv' | ForEach-Object {
  if ($_ -notlike '* *') { $_ }
} | Set-Content 'C:\CrPowershell\test\output.csv'
```

The simplest way to prompt a user for input is `Read-Host`:

```
$answer = Read-Host -Prompt 'Message'
if ($answer -eq 'y') {
  # do one thing
} else {
  # do another
}
```

In your particular case you'd probably do something like this for any matching line:

```
$anwser = Read-Host "$_`nKeep the line? [y/n] "
if ($answer -ne 'n') { $_ }
```

The above checks if the answer is *not* `n` to make removal of the line a conscious decision.

Other ways to prompt for user input are [`choice.exe`](http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tips/archive/2010/03/01/use-choice-to-prompt-for-input.aspx) (which has the additional advantage of allowing a timeout and a default answer):

```
choice.exe /c YN /d N /t 10 /m "$_`nKeep the line"
if ($LastExitCode -ne 2) { $_ }
```

or the [host UI](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730939.aspx):

```
$title   = $_
$message = 'Keep the line?'

$yes = New-Object Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription '&Yes'
$no  = New-Object Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription '&No'

$options = [Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]]($yes, $no)

$answer = $Host.UI.PromptForChoice($title, $message, $options, 1)
if ($answer -ne 1) { $_ }
```

I'm leaving it as an exercise for you to integrate whichever prompting routine you chose with the rest of the code.

Comment: thank you for the clear explanation. I learned a lot today from this. Your time is appreciated