# remove only blanks line by line with user input

Tags: csv, powershell, powershell-3.0

Yesterday I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34593427/1630171). Now I would like to do almost the same exercise with a small change: if there is a blank character on a line (go line by line in the CSV) ask the user if the blank character should be removed or not; the difference is, ONLY the blank and not the whole line.

The code which works for my previous question is:

```
$yes = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&Yes", "Retain line."
$no = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&No", "Delete line."

$n = @()

$f = Get-Content .\test.csv
foreach ($item in $f) {
    if($item -like "* *"){
        $res = $host.ui.PromptForChoice("Title", "want to keep this line? `n $item", [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]]($yes, $no), 0)
        switch ($res) {
            0 {$n+=$item}
            1 {}
        }
    } else {
        $n+=$item
    }
}

$n | Set-Content .\test.csv
```

What I think I should use is the `Trim()` function to achieve this.
So, I think I should modify in the `if` clause like below (aplogies for the silly syntax mistakes which I might do):

```
$yes = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&Yes", "Retain blank."
$no = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&No", "Delete blank."

$n = @()

$f = Get-Content .\test.csv
foreach ($item in $f) {
    if ($item -like "* *") {
        $res = $host.ui.PromptForChoice("Title", "want to keep the blank on this line? `n $item", [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]]($yes, $no), 0)
        switch ($res) {
            0 {$n+=$item.Trim()}
            1 {}
        }
    } else {
        $n+=$item.Trim()
    }
}

$n | Set-Content .\test.csv
```

This runs, but still deteles the line, so it shouldn't matter if I trimmed it or not first, I need to fix it so it will be kept or trimmed but not discarded .

**EDIT:**

Adjusting the `switch ($res)` like this doesn't work:

```
    switch ($res) {
        0 {$n+=$item.Trim()}
        1 {$n+=$item}
    }
} else {
    $n+=$item.Trim()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Trim()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trim.aspx) without parameter removes all whitespace (not just spaces) from beginning and end of a string. You can't use it for removing spaces anywhere else in a string. Instead use the [`-replace` operator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847732.aspx):

```
$_ -replace ' '
```

Note that this time you need to output the unmodified string not only if it doesn't contain a space, but also if the user chooses to keep the existing space(s).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I see the difference now. Now applied on my exercise, will simply by changing `switch ($res) {
        0 {$n+=$item -replace ' '}
        1 {$n+=$item}
    }
} else {
    $n+=$item -replace ' '
}` to this will suffice?

Comment: @CM2K More or less. You don't need to replace spaces if the line doesn't contain spaces. It doesn't hurt, but it's an unnecessary step.

Comment: tried it like this, it runs. But the space on that line is still there.

Comment: @CM2K You confused your cases. You need to replace when the answer is "no" ("don't keep the spaces", numeric value 1), not when the answer is "yes" (0).

Comment: Oh, I see. What about the `else` part, should replace be there as well or is an unnecessary step?

Comment: @CM2K That is the unnessecary step I was referring to in my first comment.

Comment: thank you for your time. I understand now. I performed the modifications and now it works.